# Forbidden You don't have permission to access <directory> on this server

Tags: rhel, http, redhat-satellite

I am working on Satellite 6.2 and I have moved like 200+GB of custom repositories to the local machine. These sub directories and files are under /home/import/XX directory, because this dir is on a different disk.

Anyways, so under the localhost/pub I created a folder called imports and from there, I created a sym link pointing to /home/imports.

The issue is on the web side, I go to http://localhost/pub/import and I can see the XX directory (one pointing to the home dir) but when I click on it I get

"Forbidden You don't have permission to access /pub/imports/XX/ on this server."

I checked the httpd.conf and made sure the FollowSymLinks was there:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

I also checked the permissions and the symbolic link looks like this

```
imports]# ll
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 54 Nov 29 14:01 XX -> /home/imports/XX
```

Further, I checked the permissions on the /home/imports/

```
ll -r /home/imports/XX/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 20 Nov 29 11:35 XX
```

Is there anything obvious am I might be missing? I've spent a few hours and I cannot find a possible answer why I cannot access it.

Comment: What happens if you su as web user (usually apache) and then try accessing the files?

Comment: I can't, the web (apache) user does not have a login shell and would not "This account is currently not available"

Comment: @user3311890 In that case you can use `sudo -u apache ls /path/to/file` You can also use `touch` or `test` or probably a half dozen other commands.

Answer (score -1):

If anybody hits the same road, even if Apache has configured the FollowSymLinks, there are other security permissions in place. This is due to a SELinux. I had to modify the `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and chnage this line `SELINUX=permissive`

After that, I rebooted the server and was able to access via web browser the files normally.

Comment: That only "works" because you turned off SELinux. You should have just changed the SELinux context of the files.